# Toggle button is not working in fragment (android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, toggle

i want to set toggle button in my fragment as a favorite button, but "setOnCheckedChangeListener" is not working i read many question on stack but i'm not able to solve my problem please help me.
this is my **xml code**

```
  <ToggleButton
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:id="@+id/fav_tog_btn"
                    android:background="@drawable/heart_white"
                    android:textOn=""
                    android:textOff=""
                    />
```

this my Kotlin code

```
  var fav_tog_btn:ToggleButton?=null

     override fun onCreateView(
         inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

         var view:View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_salons_, container, false)
         var mcontext = context

        fav_tog_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.fav_tog_btn)

         fav_tog_btn?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->

                 Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked Performed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                 if (isChecked) {
                     fav_tog_btn?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart_red)
                 } else {
                     fav_tog_btn?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart_white)
                 }

         })
}
```

Comment: `"setOnCheckedChangeListener" is not working` - do you mean that listener not called? Is `fav_tog_btn` not null and `findViewById` finds this view correctly?

Comment: yes listener is not called

Comment: as @ZSergei said check whether or not `fav_tog_btn` is not null using an `if` because if it is null `?.` will silently ignore it, although if you have it in `correct` layout `fav_tog_btn` will never be null so you can omit `?` from its declaration